# Docky make the icon jump when it needs attention

Tags: 10.10, docky

I wonder if there's any possibility to make icons in Docky jump when in need of attention.

Comment: Be more specific.Explain your problem in detail,so that your question can be answered quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought they already jumped.  On mine it jumps once and then leaves a glow at the screen edge below that icon.

I can't find anything in docky settings or gconf-editor to change the behaviour to anything else.

The glow time can be changed in gconf

/apps/docky-2/Docky/ThemeController:

```
* GlowTime = 10 -- how long the urgent indicator glow animation is (in seconds), 0 to disable, -1 for infinite
```

See Docky site [Go-Docky](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=GConf_Settings)

Comment: Happy to help!.